# can't access external hard disc files

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, accessibility

I have shared some folders on my external hard drive in the office network where I work.
After this, when I plug in the external hard drive to my home PC (Windows 7), it gives the message saying:

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder

Can you guys help me to solve this issue?
I can't use those folders and do my work. All the things came to halt because of this problem.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? Do you know how to check them?

Comment: You need to adjust the permissions on the computer sharing the drive so that "Everyone" can access them.